# Docker compose - preventing CPU thrashing when starting many services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker compose to bring up ~15 Java containers. When started one at a time, each container takes about 8 seconds to come up. Starting all of the containers together maxes out the CPU and is slower than starting the services sequentially via a shell script.

The containers have a HEALTHCHECK so I know they're fully initialised when the container status is healthy.

I would like to limit the number of containers that are starting up in parallel.

I have tried the setting the COMPOSE_PARALLEL_LIMIT but it seems to freeze after bringing up the first service. I also don't think it's waiting for the container to enter a "healthy" state.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: *may be you should clamp your cpu down better* This article looks related to the problem: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/

Comment: You could use a workaround: define a fake `dependsOn` for services, top-down and this should force `docker-compose` to start them one after another.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I considered that but would I lose the ability to start up just one service?

Comment: But you cannot start only one service with docker-compose, in any case

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Yes you can: `docker-compose up myservice`

Comment: @bcoughlan oh, I've learned something new just now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used healthchecks and depends_on

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  artifactory-8081:
    hostname: artifactory-8081
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:6.3.0
    container_name: artifactory-8081
    volumes:
      - ./data/artifactory-8081:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
      - ./data/artifactory-8081-extra:/artifactory_extra_conf
    ports:
     - 8081:8081
    environment:
     - EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "-s", "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20

  artifactory-8082:
    hostname: artifactory-8082
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:6.3.0
    container_name: artifactory-8082
    volumes:
      - ./data/artifactory-8082:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
      - ./data/artifactory-8082-extra:/artifactory_extra_conf
    ports:
     - 8082:8081
    environment:
     - EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "-s", "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
    depends_on:
      artifactory-8081:
        condition: service_healthy

  artifactory-8083:
    hostname: artifactory-8083
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:6.3.0
    container_name: artifactory-8083
    volumes:
      - ./data/artifactory-8083:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
      - ./data/artifactory-8083-extra:/artifactory_extra_conf
    ports:
     - 8083:8081
    environment:
     - EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "-s", "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
    depends_on:
      artifactory-8082:
        condition: service_healthy
```

With such docker-compose.yml it will start container by container. You have to use docker-compose 2.1+ but not 3.x, because they are dropped support of condition in depends_on. Also you have to use your own healthchecks command